# How can I log authentication errors in 3G routers?

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-commands, mobile

What command (debug) can I use to see authentication errors on a cisco 3G router specifically for the 3G connection?

Comment: You should provide some more information about how the router is configured and what kind of authentication it is using.

Comment: @DanielDib This is a practical question in general for 3G routers. I have to configure 3G routers once and a while and those routers use different kinds of authentication (ex: PAP, CHAP). I want to know if there is a general debugging mechanism to see authentication errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most 3G authentication will be done via PPP using either CHAP or PAP, so I'd start with:

```
debug ppp negotiation
debug ppp authentication
```

and see what you get back.